# Compare rows between 2 tables

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL and I need to build a database for a grocery store(not real, just a course assignment)

i have two fields from two different tables  - supplied price - the price that the store buys from the supplier and price that is given to the customers

How can I make a constraint that insures that supplied price is lower then the price that is given to the customers?

The relevant tables that I have are:

```
CREATE TABLE Supplied_Products(
[Supplier ID]   Int NOT NULL  Foreign Key References Suppliers,
[Product ID]    Int NOT NULL Foreign Key References Products,
Price           Float NOT NULL,
CHECK (Price>0),
Constraint PK_Supplied_Products PRIMARY KEY([Supplier ID] ,[Product ID])
)
CREATE TABLE Products(
[Product-ID]    Int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
[Product Name]  Varchar(20) NOT NULL,
Price           Float NOT NULL,
[Category-Name] Varchar(20) NOT NULL Foreign Key References Categories,
[Weight]        Float NOT NULL,
[Is Refrigirated] Varchar(1) DEFAULT 'N'
CHECK ([Is Refrigirated] in('Y','N')),/* Is Refrigirated can be only Y-yes or N-no*/
CHECK (Price >0)
)
```

Comment: When asking homework questions it's considered good form to show what you've done so far and explain where you're stuck.  Two bits of general guidance: the answer will depend somewhat on the database product you're using, and you should investigate CHECK constraints and perhaps triggers.

Answer (score 2):

For MS SQL Server you can't use a CHECK constraint if you want to compare data in a different table.

In this scenario I would think an INSERT & UPDATE Trigger would be required to check the value being updated.  You could then cancel the update/insert if the supplier price is more than the customer price.

Information on Triggers can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx)

Comment: No - For Homework they will likely just assume that these constraints are possible regardless of the lack of RDBMS support. At least that's what my course did!

Comment: Really? What is the point in that?  You are basically making it up as you go along.

Comment: I think for my course it was because the SQL Standard does allow these. But actually his task does look considerably more concrete than just "write a check constraint" so your answer is probably more appropriate than I first thought.

Comment: @Martin - I hope I didn't come across as having a go at you, just really threw me!

Comment: No you definitely didn't. I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use stored procedures for inserting and altering rows in both tables which checks this constraint.